# How I can show only current time using DateTime.now() in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, datetime, flutter-layout, flutter-test

```
 DateTime currentTime = new DateTime.now();

  Widget CustomCards(Color frontColor, String fetchTime) {
    Card cards = new Card(
      elevation: 1.0,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2.0, vertical: 2.0),
      color: bgColor,
      shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0),
                  child: Text(
                  currentTime.toString(),
                  style: new TextStyle(
                    fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                    fontFamily: 'Satisfy',
                    fontSize: 15.0,
                    color: frontColor,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
    return cards;
  }
```

How can I show the current time from DateTime, as it always shows the current date along with time but I want to show the time in **format hh:mm:ss**. Here ***seconds should be necessarily their***. I am not able to find any logic please help me.
Thank You

Comment: Take a look at the DateFormat class: https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html this will allow you to display the time in the format you're looking for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add Dependency in pubspec.yaml `intl: ^0.16.1` (check latest dependency from pub.dev) then you can use `DateFormat.yMMMd().format(DateTime.now());` in your dart file. You can change Pattern of Date format based on your requirement.

For custom date pattern which does not exists in DateFormat set then you can use

```
DateFormat('hh:mm:ss').format(DateTime.now());
```

Comment: I want to show hh:mm:ss only, not year or month or date. Please suggest me. Thanku for this one by the way.

Comment: @ShîvamYadav Updated answer for custom date patterns

Comment: For the updated version, visit  the [intl package page](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) and [DateFormat class](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use DateFormat class to convert it into string and your desired pattern.

Example:

```
DateFormat('your date pattern').format(currentTime);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will format the time according to our `time zone` and it takes `BuildContent`

```
TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(DateTime.now()).format(context)
```

For example, the current time is `7:25 PM` so this will return you the same.